# Solving linear matrix system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Having the matrix equation $XA = Z$, where $X$ and $Z$ are two constant unitary matrices, so how to solve the system to get the matrix $A$? Is the matrix $A$ unitary too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of a [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) $\ X\ $ is its [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) $\ X^\dagger\ $. Therefore, if you multiply both sides of the equation $\ XA=Z\ $ by $\ X^\dagger\ $ you'll get
$$
A=X^\dagger Z\ .
$$
Since products and inverses of unitary matrices are unitary, then $\ A\ $ will also be unitary.